# How to place text to follow an 3d object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing AR App with Vuforia library in Unity.

I want that text must place above of sphere all the time. At same time, text must look to screen front face. (text should remain constant, should not return)

[image: in edit screen]

[image: in app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the text as a child of the planet and in update do

```
void Update(){
text.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position);
}
```

Comment: With this code the text and sphere intersect at some angles. You can see this here: [image](https://i.imgur.com/05lU7DX.png)

Comment: move the child text in the game object, it should stay a constant distance from the sphere, where you place it if you have parented it correctly